# FileWriter not putting 0's into my output file

Tags: java, object, tostring, filewriter

I have this being performed on a button click event
The employee class has a toString method which would display everything that it took to make that object. 
Once it gets to print the zipcode using FileWriter though, the first 0 in place doesn't show up.

```
private class ButtonListenerSubmit implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {
        int phone, zipcode;
        double pay;
        String phoneString, zipcodeString, payString;
        phoneString = phoneNumberTF.getText();
        zipcodeString = zipcodeTF.getText();
        payString = payRateTF.getText();
        phone = Integer.parseInt(phoneString);
        zipcode = Integer.parseInt(zipcodeString);
        pay = Double.parseDouble(payString);

        Employee one = new Employee(fNameTF.getText(), lNameTF.getText(), addressTF.getText(), townTF.getText(), stateTF.getText(), zipcode, phone, pay);
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(one.lastName + one.firstName + ".txt"));
            out.println(one);
            out.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly does zipcodeTF.getText() return? zipcode is an int but a getText method insinuates returning a string

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that your `zipcode` is an `int` integers won't hold `012345` they'll automatically truncate it to `12345`.

Try a string.

Answer (score 0):

Make the data type of the zip code String

Answer (score 0):

You should use `zipcodeString` as a argument in `Employee` class initialization. Also you will not get full phone number if you add a phone number which starts with 0 while using `phone` variable. Because integer avoids 0 if it is a first character. So use `zipecodeString` and `phoneString` to get full input.

Try this:

```
Employee one = new Employee(fNameTF.getText(), lNameTF.getText(), addressTF.getText(), townTF.getText(), stateTF.getText(), zipcodeString, phoneString, pay);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add padding to your zipcode field in `Employee.toString` method. Replace this:

```
... + "ZipCode: " + zipCode + ... // or whatever code you have for this
```

With this:

```
... + "ZipCode: " + String.format("%s5", zipCode).replaceAll(" ", "0") + ...
```